# Variable entity doesn't exist in template, how to fix it?

Tags: symfony, twig

Here is my template architecture :

```
list.html.twig => question.html.twig => tagList.html.twig => tagBadge.html.twig
```

In my tag list, I have a `tag` variable that is well recognized, but in the tagBadge that is included, I get the error `Variable tag does not exist`.

I don't know what is the origin of the error. Maybe Twig can't follow the track of variables after a certain depth of inclusion ? I checked for invisible characters in my files. I verified my syntax again and again, but maybe my error is simple...

tagList.html.twig

> {% for tag in tags %}
>
> {{tag.name}}{# tag is recognized #}
>
> {% include 'tag/partials/tagBadge.html.twig' with {'tag': tag} %}
>      {# tag is not recognized in template #}
>
> {% endfor %}

tagBadge.html.twig

> {{tag.name}}

My question: why `tag` is not recognized in my second template 'tagBadge'. I'm working with Symfony 4.2.

Comment: Looks valid to me. Are you defining `tag` elsewhere?

Comment: Full error message (including stacktrace) would be helpful.

Comment: Are you using a `macro` inside `tagBadge.html.twig`?

Comment: The full message is : "The variable tag does not exist"

I tried to put the stack trace in spoiler but it's too long for the comment field (I'nooby on slack) @Jakub Matczack

Tag is an entity I get in a controller. But this bug is reproductible with some random variable passed to my template : example {'str': 'some random string'}. I get the same error with test variable.

However, the global app.user variable is available.

Comment: Nop @DarBee, I've only {{tag.name}} as html hypertext.

Comment: use render controller instead , https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Comment: @hous why would/should he do that? The code he posted should work as is. See [here](https://twigfiddle.com/gwg8ka)

Comment: So is there an error message appears ? can we see it

Comment: Here's screenshot for error message and stack trace (@Jakub Matczak), cut in 3 different images cause the stack trace is too long :

![error1](http://www.noelshack.com/2019-02-4-1547144788-error1.png).

![error2](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/02/4/1547144797-error-2.png).

![error3](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/02/4/1547144803-error-3.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found this week end the mistake I did. It appeared that I used my template in to different places of my view. It wasn't that use of the template which throw the error, but another I totally forgot, to which I didn't pass the variable... I feel dumb ;) let my mistake be useful for others !